# SpriteKit friction not seeming to working properly

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, xcode7

On a project in Xcode 7 I have a few `SKSpriteNodes` that move back and forth on the screen and another one, called `user`, that is meant to jump from sprite to sprite, progressively up the screen. However, when `user` lands on one of the moving sprites the moving sprite just slides right out from under it and `user` falls back down. I thought that this meant that I needed to increase the friction property on the nodes so that `user` would "stick" to the nodes, but this just makes it bounce on the other nodes. My problem is that the nodes moving back and forth seem to "slippery," and `user` just doesn't stay on them.

Here's my code:

My class for `user`:

```
class UserNode: SKSpriteNode
{
    class func newNode(position position: CGPoint) -> UserNode
    {
        let position = position

        let sprite = UserNode(imageNamed: "userImage")
        sprite.position = position
        sprite.size = CGSize(width: sprite.size.width * 2, height: sprite.size.height * 2)
        sprite.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: "userImage"), size: sprite.size)
        sprite.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
        sprite.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
        sprite.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
        sprite.physicsBody?.friction = 0.2

        return sprite
    }
}
```

and for moving `user` (the methods in my `gamescene`)

```
let scale: CGFloat = 2.0
let damping: CGFloat = 0.98
var point = CGPoint?()

func moveNodeToPoint(sprite: SKSpriteNode, point: CGPoint)
{
    let dx = (point.x - sprite.position.x) * scale
    let dy = (point.y - sprite.position.y) * scale
    sprite.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVectorMake(dx, dy)
}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?)
{
    /* Called when a touch begins */
    for _: AnyObject in touches
    {
        if !welcomeNode.hidden
        {
            let fadeAway = SKAction.fadeOutWithDuration(0.3)

            welcomeNode.runAction(fadeAway)
            directionsNode.runAction(fadeAway)
            touchStartNode.runAction(fadeAway)

            welcomeNode.hidden = true
            directionsNode.hidden = true
            touchStartNode.hidden = true
        }

        //////////

        point = CGPointMake(self.frame.midX, user.position.y + 300)


    }
}

override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?)
{
    point = nil
}

override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval)
{
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */

    if (point != nil)
    {
        moveNodeToPoint(user, point: point!)
    }
    else
    {
        let dx = user.physicsBody!.velocity.dx * damping
        let dy = user.physicsBody!.velocity.dy * damping

        user.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVectorMake(dx, dy)
    }



}
```

and for moving the platforms:

```
let screenSize = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
let width = screenSize.size.width * 2
let firstAction = SKAction.moveBy(CGVector(dx: width, dy: 0), duration: 2)
let secondAction = SKAction.moveBy(CGVector(dx: -width, dy: 0), duration: 2)

let actions = [firstAction, secondAction]
let barAction = SKAction.sequence(actions)
let mainBarAction = SKAction.repeatActionForever(barAction)

platform.runAction(mainBarAction)
```

Comment: Did you increase the friction on the platforms?

Comment: I guess you move your 'moving' sprite using `SKAction`?

Comment: Yes, I tried increasing the friction on the platforms @Gliderman

Comment: I'm actually moving it by changing it's velocity @WangYudong

Comment: @isaac  I know this is a stupid thing to ask, but did you increase the friction on both the platform and the `user` at the same time?  And maybe the velocity needs to be changed using impulses instead?

Comment: Can you show the code for adding `user` and `moving sprites`?

Comment: I did try increasing the friction on both, but I'm not sure what an impulse is (sorry I'm still new with iOS). Could you give me a link or something? @Gilderman

Comment: I added code @WandYudong

Comment: You didn't type my name right :)

Comment: Move your platform by changing its `velocity` as will. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32513802/how-to-make-sprite-sit-on-a-moving-sprite/32517953#32517953