# how to achieve a swimming box effect

Tags: swift3, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skphysicsbody

I am trying to add a behaviour for a box, so that it feels "natural" when the box hits a 2d water surface. 
The goal that I am trying to achieve sounds so simple, but I just do not know how to approach this problem in a right way.

Attached you find a sketch. the brown box is in the air and falls down on the blue water. when the box hits the water, the box should sink a little bit down under the water, but not completely, since the box should swim on the surface.

How does the physicsBody of the SpriteNode help me?
I would be so happy if you could give me a helping hand.

Thanks in advance.

[image: sketch]

Comment: Take a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/25353062/3402095

Comment: cool, thank you for the link @Whirlwind

Comment: @Whirlwind Thanks again for your awesome help.